# Go RoundTripper and Transport

Tags: http, go, roundtrip, itmstransporter

I am having hard time understanding what we need `RoundTripper` for in Go.

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#RoundTripper

Explains the default `Transport` in Go:

```
var DefaultTransport RoundTripper = &Transport{
       Proxy: ProxyFromEnvironment,
       Dial: (&net.Dialer{
               Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
               KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
       }).Dial,
       TLSHandshakeTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
}
```

But what would be the difference between `RoundTripper` and this:

```
transport := &http.Transport{
    Proxy:                 http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
    TLSHandshakeTimeout:   timeout,
    Dial:              dialfunc,
    DisableKeepAlives: true,
}
```

My question: is `RoundTripper` different than regular `Transport`?

Comment: Do you want to know what `RoundTripper` is for or do you want to know why `DefaultTransport` has the type `RoundTripper`? Because the interface `RoundTripper` exists to do round trips.

Comment: I want to know what RoundTripper is

Comment: From the documentation: "RoundTripper is an interface representing the ability to execute a single HTTP transaction, obtaining the Response for a given Request." It sits in between the low level stuff like dialing, tcp, etc. and the high level details of HTTP (redirects, etc.) RoundTrip is *the* method do do a single round trip of request sent to server, server answers with response.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think Volker got it right in his comment on your question.  From my perspective, `http.Transport` provides an implementation of `http.RoundTripper`, but you can provide your own that is completely different, as long as it implements `RoundTrip()`.

A number of folks have used this as the way to add rate limiting (i.e. they provide an implementation which may use `http.Transport` under the covers, but they add the ability to constrain the rate at which your program sends or receives bytes).